# Phonegap Android dynamic anchor tel: or mailto: not interpreted

Tags: java, android, jquery, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 5.5.0, and trying to dynamically add anchor links based on AJAX JSON response data, using for example this code snippet:

HTML:

```
<div class="profileData col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="phoneNumber">
    <figure><img id="phoneNumberImage" alt="Phone number" src="img/profile_picto_phone.png"/></figure> 
    <span></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#phoneNumber span").append("<a>" + data.profile.tel + "</a>").click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'tel:' + data.profile.tel;
});
```

This works fine in iOS, and also works in Android with a hardcoded link using no jQuery like this:

```
<a onClick="window.location.href='tel:12345678'">12345678</a>
```

It's like the links are not interpreted anymore because they're being added dynamically. I already tried adding `.trigger('create')` as some other posts suggested, but no success. The links appear in my Android app, but clicking on it triggers nothing. No logs in Android Studio except for:

```
V/WebViewInputDispatcher: blockWebkitDraw
V/WebViewInputDispatcher: blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
D/webview: blockWebkitViewMessage= false
```

My `config.xml` contains:

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<uses-permission android:autoLink="email" />
<uses-permission android:autoLink="phone" />
```